# How to generate an Azure IoT hub SAS token for one device/service only?

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I want to generate a new SAS token for accessing an Azure IoT Hub using Paho MQTT with Java. I want to retrieve MQTT messages from a backend Java service.

Of course I want to limit the access for each service instance to certain devices.

This is the command I use to generate the token.

`az iot hub generate-sas-token -d device1 -n iothubname --policy device`

This is the error message I get

```
{u'ExceptionMessage': u'Tracking ID<HIDDEN`enter code here`>:TimeStamp:01/01/2019 14:30:33', u'Message': u'ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized'}
```

Before I tried that, I tried to use the policy "service" (because that token should be used by the backend service) which didn't work either:

```
az iot hub generate-sas-token -d device1 -n iothubname --policy service
```

```
{u'ExceptionMessage': u'Tracking ID:<>TimeStamp:01/01/2019 14:37:39', u'Message': u'ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized'}
```

The only thing that works is `az iot hub generate-sas-token -n iothubname` but regarding the documentation this creates a token with the iothubowner policy which I don't want to give my backend service.

I can't really understand the concept of permissions on the Azure IoT Hub even after reading the docs 3 times: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#iot-hub-permissions

When would I use the `service` policy and when would I use the `device` policy?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please let me know if you have used az login to first login to Azure? Please check this link for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login

Comment: yes I have used that, otherwise the command `az iot hub generate-sas-token -n iothubname` wouldn't have worked I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
az iot hub generate-sas-token -n [IoTHub Name] --policy registryRead --key-type secondary
```

you can see the details of the same in the example in the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-iot-ext-az-iot-hub-generate-sas-token